# Three.js rendering in dynamic Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, three.js, rendering

Currently working on a dynamically created `three.js` component in Angular. The statically (via selector) created **Plot3dComponent** works perfectly. But when creating it dynamically via ComponentFactoryResolver the component does not render anything. Also tried adding some delays with `setTimeout` but I can't get it to render anything. The image output of the `save` function is just a white rectangle with the wanted width and height, like the canvas element is. Do you have any ideas?

My template to render the component in

```html
<ng-container #plot3dref></ng-container>
```

The minified component class looks like this

```js
@ViewChild('plot3dref', {read: ViewContainerRef}) plot3dref: ViewContainerRef;

save(geometry: Geometry) {
  const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(Plot3dComponent);
  const componentRef = this.plot3dref.createComponent(componentFactory);
  const instance = (<Plot3dComponent>componentRef.instance);

  instance.geometry = geometry;
  instance.materials = this.materials;
  instance.selectedBlock = -1;

  console.log(instance.save());
}, 100);
```

The minified **Plot3dComponent** looks like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-plot-3d',
  template: '<canvas #canvas></canvas>',
  styles: [`:host { width: 100%; } canvas { width: 100%; }`],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class Plot3dComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('canvas') private canvasRef: ElementRef;
  @Input() geometry: Geometry;
  @Input() selectedBlock: number;
  @Input() materials: Material[];
  [...]

  ngOnInit() { this.render = this.render.bind(this); }
  save() { return this.canvasRef.nativeElement.toDataURL(); }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.startRendering();
  }

  private startRendering() {
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: this.canvas,
      antialias: true,
      preserveDrawingBuffer: true
    });

    const component: Plot3dComponent = this;

    (function render() {
      component.render();
    }());
  }
}
```

Thanks, cheers!

**Edit:** The issue seems to occur in *@angular/material*'s `mat-tab-groups` as well. Also tested fixed heights in there.

Comment: Try adding a `height: 100%` to the host.

Comment: Does not work, tried `height: 100%` on :host, canvas and both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually got it working with both, static and dynamic component creation. Created a minimal [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-component-threejs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic.component.ts) with the working example. This is the related code snippet.

```js
export class DynamicComponent {
  @ViewChild('canvas') private canvasRef: ElementRef;
  [...]

  ngOnInit() {
    const renderer = new WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(200, 150);
    this.canvasRef.nativeElement.append(renderer.domElement);
    [...]
}
```